XPath with nested condition using outside element value
My XPath foo is not yet good enough to figure out how to do the following.
I have an XML that's similar to:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <books>
    <book>
      <name>Fantastic World of Peggy</name>
      <category>fiction</category>
      <author-ref>/SanDiego/Peter</author-ref>
    </book>
  </books>
  <cities>
    <name>SanDiego</name>
    <authors>
      <author>
        <name>Peter</name>
        <awards-won>true</awards-won>
        <pet>pike</pet>
      </author>
    </authors>
  </cities>
</root>

Now I want to access all the books where the author has won a prize.
I end up with the following XPath in my mind (which does not work):
//books[category = 'fiction' and //author[name = string-after(<the-current-book>/author-ref, '/SanDiego/') and awards-won = 'true']]

and this one where I want to print the pet name of the author aswell as the book title:
//books[category = 'fiction']/concat(name, concat(' - ', //author[name = string-after(<the-current-book>/author-ref, '/SanDiego/') and awards-won = 'true']/pet))

<the-current-book> must be a reference to the book that is the current object in the outside condition.
I can hard-code the cities part as in my XMLs there is only one city but there are many books and many authors.
I have not yet found how to do this in XPath.
Any suggestions on how to do this?

It would be really helpful if you gave an example of what you wanted your XPath to actually return. It's not clear what the logic should be. Perhaps extend your sample data to include a few more authors and books, and give a desired output? And please specify the XPath version available to you (e.g. are you stuck with using an old XPath 1 interpreter embedded in some other "platform"?), because that makes a big difference. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I'm not exactly sure what sort of output you're looking for and you don't specify a version of xpath, but here's an XPath 3.1 option...
for $award_winning_author in /root/cities/authors/author[awards-won='true'] 
return
    let $author-ref := '/' || $award_winning_author/../../name || '/' || $award_winning_author/name return
    let $pet := if ($award_winning_author/pet) then ' (pet: ' || $award_winning_author/pet || ')' else '' return 
    for $book in /root/books/book[author-ref=$author-ref] 
    return
        $book/name || ' - ' || tokenize($author-ref,'/')[last()] || $pet

Using your sample input, here is the output...
Fantastic World of Peggy - Peter (pet: pike)


That's a great suggestion, thanks. I thought that for was an XQuery function and not part of XPath. I guess then that I can't access outside 'elements' inside a new scope then?

I don't think this is even possible to do in a single XPath 1.0 expression, but there are many ways to do it in XPath 2 or 3. I voted for Daniel Haley's answer, above, but I thought I'd add a variation of his query, using multiple variables in a for expression for a bit more compactness, and moving the handling of pet into the return clause.
for 
  $city in /root/cities,
  $author in $city/authors/author[awards-won='true'],
  $author-ref in concat('/', $city/name, '/', $author/name),
  $book in /root/books/book[category='fiction'][author-ref = $author-ref]
return
  $book/concat(
    name, 
    ' - ', 
    $author/name, 
    $author/pet/concat(' (pet: ', ., ')')
  )

Run with sample input:
<root>
  <books>
    <book>
      <name>Fantastic World of Peggy</name>
      <category>fiction</category>
      <author-ref>/SanDiego/Peter</author-ref>
    </book>
    <book>
      <name>Mundane World of Jane</name>
      <category>fiction</category>
      <author-ref>/SanDiego/Paul</author-ref>
    </book>
    <book>
      <name>Awesome World of Anne</name>
      <category>fiction</category>
      <author-ref>/SanDiego/Peter</author-ref>
    </book>
    <book>
      <name>Middling World of Mary</name>
      <category>fiction</category>
      <author-ref>/SanDiego/John</author-ref>
    </book>
  </books>
  <cities>
    <name>SanDiego</name>
    <authors>
      <author>
        <name>John</name>
        <awards-won>true</awards-won>
      </author>
      <author>
        <name>Peter</name>
        <awards-won>true</awards-won>
        <pet>pike</pet>
      </author>
      <author>
        <name>Paul</name>
        <awards-won>false</awards-won>
        <pet>paulo</pet>
      </author>
    </authors>
  </cities>
</root>

It produces the following sequence of strings:
(
  "Middling World of Mary - John",
  "Fantastic World of Peggy - Peter (pet: pike)",
  "Awesome World of Anne - Peter (pet: pike)"
)

EDITED to illustrate the idea of building an index for more efficient lookup of authors by name. If you were dealing with a large dataset where efficiency was a real concern, then you might want to create an efficient index (using a map) to associate each author with an author-ref key, and iterate over the book elements, calling the map as a function, passing it the book element's author-ref value. This is like defining a key in XSLT. Looking up an author-ref in the map using $authors($author-ref) will be faster than //authors[author-ref=$author-ref] which will be a linear search.
for 
  $authors in map:merge(
    /root/cities/authors/author[awards-won = "true"]
      /map:entry(
        concat("/", ../preceding-sibling::name[1], "/", name), 
        .
      )
  ),
  $book in /root/books/book[category = "fiction"],
  $author in $book/author-ref/$authors(.)
return
  $book/concat(
    name, 
    ' - ', 
    $author/name, 
    $author/pet/concat(' (pet: ', ., ')')
  )

Using a for statement to iterate over values for $authors, $book, and $author, has the effect of "projecting" a three-column table of data, with every combination of those values.
Since the $authors variable generates a single item (a map relating author-ref keys to author values), that same item will appear in every row of the table, and won't effect the number of rows.
The $book variable iterates over each non-fiction book, and the $author variable iterators over the award-winning authors of each of those $book values. So you'll get a row for each combination of $book and its matching $author. Note that a book which doesn't have an award-winning author will therefore not appear in the table.
The return clause then produces a result for each row in that table; i.e. every book by an award-winning author.
The $author/pet expression in the return expression will sometimes yield an empty sequence, and in those cases, the remainder of the path /concat(' (pet: ', ., ')') will not get evaluated. This means that   (pet: ... ) won't appear if an author doesn't have a pet name.
A difference between this XPath query and the earlier one is that the values here will be in book order rather than  city+author+book order.
